# Rails, One controller and one model but many templates, need advice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, partial

I have one model with a lot of attributes and one controller, but I also have nearly 100 templates. Approximately 90% of fields and view in this templates are the same. User can fill any template, save it and ,as needed, print it as PDF. What is the best approach of implementing this kind of relation?
I see only one way:
1. 1 model, 100 controllers(because all templates have to have all REST actions) and included module with same actions for all, and 100 shared partials for form and view.

Ideally, of course, 1 model, 1 controller per template, but it is not the DRY'st way.

Am I wrong? And there is another simple way with one model, one controller and 100 partials?
Will be appreciate for any advice.

Comment: How about use a route with constraint parameter pointing to one controller and use parameter to decide which template will be shown ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that could be implemented provided your scenario is simple. (I am giving this because you have not mentioned anything about the so called templates and types of fields).

Anyway, have one controller and one model (Because you say 90% fields are same. Having 10% nulls aint a big deal). Then create a form with all these fields organized as templates. Have a select box to select the template and based on that hide or show your fields with JavaScript.

Assuming you have a field to indicate template_type in your model you wont be having any problem saving this and displaying. Or even switching templates by editing your model.